# logger.debug not writing to log file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to debug a model in Rails so I'm using this code:
`logger.debug('asasd')`

However, I'm tailing the log file development.log but I'm not seeing it add to this file.

1. I am certain this module is being run
2. I have confirmed that runtime errors are logging to this file, and I see them when I tail.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that you have set the log level to debug in environments/appropriate_env_file.rb:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

and also make sure you are tailing the correct log file based on the environment you are running against.

Comment: I found this question relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635527/no-log-messages-in-production-log - at least one version of rails had a known issue with this.

Answer (score 4):

You could attempt to call `flush` on the logger to force it to write to this file. Usually this would happen after every request:

```
logger.debug("asasd")
logger.flush
```

There's also the `auto_flushing` setting on the `Rails.logger` instance itself:

```
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = true
```

This will make the call to `logger.flush` unnecessary, as Rails will automatically flush the buffered output to the log file whenever it is written to.

Comment: Additionally, `logger.flush` is now a deprecated, no-op method.