# No log messages in production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I wrote a demo HelloWorld Rails app and tested it with WEBrick (it doesn't even use a DB, it's just a controller which prints "hello world"). Then I tried to deploy it to a local Apache powered with Passenger. In fact this test is just to get Passenger working (it's my first deploy on Apache). Now I'm not even sure that Passenger works, but I don't get any error on the Apache side.

When I fire `http://rails.test/` the browser shows the Rails 500 error page - so I assume that Passenger works. **I want to investigate the logs, but it happens that production.log is empty!** I don't think it's a permission problem, because if I delete the file, it is recreated when I reload the page. I tried to change the log level in `conf/environments/production.rb`, tried to manually write to log file with Rails console production and

```
 Rails.logger.error('asdf')
```

it returns `true` but nothing gets written to production.log. The path (obtained per Rails.logger.inspect) is correct, and I remark that the file is recreated if I manually remove it. How can I know what's going on?

*(I already checked the Apache logs, plus I set the highest debug level for Passenger but it seems a Rails problem, so is not logged by the server)*

Comment: I'm still having this problem, even though i'm in rails 4....what did you end up doing?

Comment: Just upgraded Rails. It might be a regression

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're running Rails 3.2.1, this is a bug. It was [patched in 3.2.2](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/1/ann-rails-3-2-2-has-been-released).

If you can't upgrade to 3.2.2 for any reason, [this comment on GitHub has a workaround](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277#issuecomment-3999463):

```
# config/initializers/patch_rails_production_logging.rb
Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logger).instance_variable_get(:@log_dest).sync = true if Rails.logger
```

Comment: The strange thing is that I played with `Logger.flush` in the Rails console, but it didn't have any effect. Upgrading solved my issue

Comment: Glad that helped. I updated the answer with a workaround for anyone who can't upgrade.

Comment: `undefined method 'sync=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` with rails 4.1.2

Comment: You shouldn't need this in Rails 4. This was fixed in Rails 3.2.2, and this answer is just a workaround for people on Rails 3.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Setting this works on Rails 3.2.11:

```
Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(Rails.root.join("log","production.log"))
```

Comment: hi - where do i add this line?

Comment: I put this into an initializer under config. for example, in `config/initializers/logger.rb`: `if !Rails.env.development?
  Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(Rails.root.join("log","#{Rails.env}.log"))
end`
Seriously, how do I get a newline without cut-pasting in a newline? If I hit the enter key is saves my edit.