# Rails logger not outputting anything to development.log

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

I have new Rails 4 app, Im using `pow 0.5.0` and in some of my controllers I am intentionally logging some code out using `logger.debug "Test"`.

For some reason absolutely nothing is being written to the `log/development.log` file.

I have checked the permissions on the file and folder and everything is fine.

Comment: Try check this link, hopefully it helps: [logger.debug not writing to log file in Rails][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559708/logger-debug-not-writing-to-log-file-in-rails

Comment: for normal debugging look at [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) :)